# Recover $G$-representation from restriction and quotient

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $H$. Suppose there is an unknown $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module $M$, where we know $M_1 = \mathrm{res}^G_H M$ and $M_2 = M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}\mathbb{Z}$. Is there some way of classifying the possibilities for $M$, in terms of $M_1$ and $M_2$ (maybe some cohomology group)?

(I'm actually interested in the case where $G$ is profinite and $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but realized I didn't know the more basic version of this.)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.